# Steam API Get steam level of user?

Tags: steam

Does anybody know if it's possible to get the steam level of a user?

there is nothing on the wiki

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nevermind i figured it out!   it's http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetSteamLevel/v1/?key=KEYHERE1&steamid=STEAMIDHERE

Comment: How did you find this out? its not on the steam page here: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API